# Replace symbol reference in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-refactoring

Is there any way in the VS 13 to replace a symbol reference/function call? for example: I'd like to replace all `foo.baa("something")` by `newMethod("something")` (the arguments must be preserved).

Comment: `CTRL + H` allows you to search a file and replace all instances of something with a new criteria. Maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: I wasn't exactly looking for a text replacement like this(which I'm aware of) but a real code refactoring. But I think there's no such a thing in the VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the method name at the declaration you will have the option to rename refactor all instances of it. If that's not an option, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and do a replace all across entire solution. If your argument names vary, you can use the regular expressions option in that find and replace tool like so:

[image]